# How can I make sprites and tile-sets interact with y-sort correctly in Godot?

Tags: godot, depth

Y-sort is not working how I would expect in Godot.  I have a player sprite, their feet are at the origin.  I have a y-sorted tile layer.  The mushroom base is at the bottom of the tile, it doesn't start in the middle or anything.

When I stand in front of a mushroom title, it displays in front when it should be behind.  If I step down just a bit, it finally pops behind.  It seems like Godot thinks that the y-position of my player is near their center.  I don't know why.

What other steps need to be taken to make y-sort work as expected?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible solution, but changing y-offset for the character sprite to some random position mostly fixed the issue:
[image]

Comment: I noticed this "Centered" checkbox in your screenshot. What does that do? Maybe that's the problem? (Just guessing)

Comment: There's an origin position ("+" symbol near her knees).  If disabled, that becomes the top left corner of the sprite.